# What exactly is license boilerplate commenting and what format does it need to be in?

Tags: c++, coding-style, boilerplate, comments

I was reading through the *Google C++ Style Guide* to try to emulate good coding practices. When I read through the section on how to comment my code, it asks me to start each file with [license boilerplate](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#File_Comments). All I could find out about this terminology was from *Mozilla* and what I believe to be [their commenting standards](https://www.mozilla.org/MPL/boilerplate-1.1/). What exactly is license boilerplate commenting and what format does it need to be in?

*Note: To be clear, I'm not saying the Google C++ Style Guide is the perfect guide to follow for good coding practices. I'm just using it to gain new ideas on how to better my coding style.*

Comment: For example [see here](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.en.html) for the comment block associated with the GPL. It states things like authors, releasability, who can modify the code, if people can charge for software developed with this code, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I didn't know that commercial code needed each source file to be documented with license and terms agreements. That makes sense since it's intellectual property.

Comment: The google C++ style guide is not considered good practice in many parts for modern C++ (but its a long time since I personally read it). It is considered good style for internal google C++ code that needs to match the current C++ code used at google.

Comment: @Loki Astari, I agree with you. There's much that I choose to ignore from Google's style guide such as the use of printf() instead of cout streams. I'm using their guide mainly to form a basis for how I want to structure my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"License boilerplate" is a comment block placed at the beginning of each source code file that describes or names the license or terms that the source code has been placed under. If there is a specific commenting style that is required to use then the license itself will describe it, otherwise one is free to use any style they like.

Comment: Thank you for the concise description of what license boilerplate really is.